# What is the simplest method to extract success from a list of Scala futures?

Tags: scala

Let's say we have a sequence of Scala `Future` results like `val futures: Seq[Future[Boolean]]` and let's say I'd like to get a `Future[Boolean]` that returns the first `true` result, but otherwise fails or returns false normally.

At the moment the current implementation I have is something like this:

```
// convert to Seq[Future[Try[Boolean]]]
val tries = futures.map{ _.map(Success(_)).recover{ case t: Throwable => Failure(t) } }

val sequence = Future.sequence(tries)

// first positive
val positive = sequence.map{ _.find{ case Success(true) => true; case _ => false } }
val nonpositive = sequence.map{ _.find{ case Success(true) => false; case _ => true } }

// prioritise positive results over other results
val futureTry =
  for {
    p <- positive
    n <- nonpositive
  } yield( p.orElse(n) )

// convert from Future[Try[Boolean]] back to Future[Boolean]
val future = futureTry.map { _.map { t => t.get } }
```

Is there a simpler way to write the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Future.find`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@find[T]%28futures:TraversableOnce[scala.concurrent.Future[T]]%29%28p:T=%3EBoolean%29%28implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[Option[T]]), and since you are looking for a `Boolean`, you can pass the `identity` function :

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

val failedF = Future.failed[Boolean](new Exception("boo"))
val falseF  = Future.successful(false)
val trueF   = Future.successful(true)

val f1 = Future.find(trueF :: falseF :: failedF :: Nil)(identity) 
val f2 = Future.find(falseF :: failedF :: Nil)(identity)
val f3 = Future.find(failedF :: Nil)(identity)

Future.sequence(f1 :: f2 :: f3 :: Nil).foreach(println)
// List(Some(true), None, None)
```

It returns `Future[Option[Boolean]]` like it is, but you could easily turn it into `Future[Boolean]` by supplying a default value with `getOrElse` :

```
f2.map(_.getOrElse(false)).foreach(println)
// false
```

Comment: That looks great, the only thing it lacks from the implementation above is that failure must propagate if success is not found. In the above it we just loose any failures as they get converted to `None`. Is there a simple way around this?

Comment: A possible way would be to do something similar as my last example but return the failed `Future` which you get with `Future.sequence` : `f3.flatMap(_.map(Future.successful _).getOrElse(Future.sequence(failedF :: Nil).map(_.head)))`, but this doesn't look really nice.